# Windows Activation Errors

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-activation

I have an Acer Aspire 5 Laptop that is very recently bought and came with Windows 10 pre-installed. It was never activated, and a blank page showed up in the Activation Menu of Settings. I tried to repair the tokens.dat file as suggested by microsoft itself, but it turned out that i do not have the file path at all. The folder that would normally contain the tokens.dat repair file was not there. The file path to that would normally be C:\Windows \ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WSLicense. The last WSLicense folder doesn't exist on my laptop. Any way to fix this would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Would it be acceptable for you to do a clean re-install of Windows? You can download the required files directly from Microsoft. // Does the device actually have a [Microsoft Certificate of Authenticity](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/howtotell/hardware.aspx) somewhere?

Comment: Now that I think of it, no, It didn't come with one.

Comment: Acer Aspire 5 are also available without operating system. Could you provide the exact product name (should be similar to “NX.GSWEV.005”)? Are you sure the seller promised that it comes with Windows 10?

Comment: Yeah, it is NX.GS3EK.001. The seller promised Windows, but now that I look at it, it says its linux. I think I will reinstall windows 10 with an iso image. Thanks tho

Comment: This particular model should come with Windows 10 Home. If you’re never asked for a key, everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the the comment about reinstalling Windows, if the laptop is new, it should be activated out of the box. Can you contact the vendor of the machine and see if they can help you.

Comment: Yeah, I did contact the vendor, and they just cut contact about two weeks back. No response. No, I'm not taking this to court, as I'm a 14-year old kid.

Comment: The licensing for the machine is held in the Microsoft Licensing Server. If not activated, there is not likely a license there. If you try to reinstall, you may have to purchase the license. I would suggest first contacting Microsoft Sales Support (Microsoft,com - contact us) and see if they can help activate using the product code label

Comment: Technically, the license (should) be embedded in the firmware. The activation service only comes into play once the system is online. Of course, a preinstalled system should be preactivated.